# How to scrape data bypassing radio button using request in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, request, python-requests

I want to scrape data from [this website](https://mahagst.gov.in/en/know-your-taxpayer). After visiting, we need to select radio button criteria as 'TIN', then
enter the TIN no. as  '27680809621V' & click on submit button. I don't know how to do I'm stuck, as there is no name or value.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = requests.session()
req = s.get('https://mahagst.gov.in/en/know-your-taxpayer')
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text,'lxml')

dictinfo = {i['name']:i.get('value','') for i in soup.select('input[name]')}
```

Someone please help me.

Comment: what exactly do you want to scrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selection makes a GET request with selected Tin :) This is how you will get the json response back, and therefore, no need for BeautifulSoup.

```
from requests import Session

s = Session()
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) '\
                         'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '\
                         'Chrome/75.0.3770.80 Safari/537.36',
          'Accept': 'application/json'
}
# Add headers
s.headers.update(headers)


BASE_URL = 'https://mahagst.gov.in/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZMSTD_KYT_SRV/TinDetailSet'

params = {
    "$filter": "(Tin eq '27680809621V')"
}

r = s.get(BASE_URL, params=params)

data = r.json()
print(data)
```

This is how I found out the URL and params
[image]

And the data return is a beautiful json(dictionary) :)
[image]

The data is a dictionary and list. So you can use your Python skills to get the variables out. e.g. `data['d']['results']` :) Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably get the content you need through the same URL used by the website, i.e. `https://mahagst.gov.in/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZMSTD_KYT_SRV/TinDetailSet?$filter=(Tin eq '27680809621V')`, by replacing the `TIN number`.

Alternatively, you could use Selenium to check the radio button, fill the input, and get the data.