# Python: xpath to extract dates

Tags: python, xpath

I would like to extract the date of `31-Dec-19` but unable to do so

```
IC = requests.get('https://www.reuters.com/companies/IMAX.P/financials/income-statement-annual')
IC = html.fromstring(IC.content)
columns = IC.xpath('//th/span/text()')
>>['Revenue', 'Total Revenue', 'Cost of Revenue, Total', 'Gross Profit', 'Selling/General/Admin. Expenses, Total', 'Research & Development', 'Unusual Expense (Income)'
, 'Total Operating Expense', 'Operating Income', 'Interest Inc.(Exp.),Net-Non-Op., Total', 'Other, Net', 'Net Income Before Taxes', 'Provision for Income Taxes', 'Ne
t Income After Taxes', 'Net Income Before Extra. Items', 'Total Extraordinary Items', 'Net Income', 'Income Available to Com Excl ExtraOrd', 'Income Available to Com
 Incl ExtraOrd', 'Diluted Net Income', 'Diluted Weighted Average Shares', 'Diluted EPS Excluding ExtraOrd Items', 'DPS - Common Stock Primary Issue', 'Diluted Normal
ized EPS', 'Interest Exp.(Inc.),Net-Operating, Total', 'Dilution Adjustment', 'Depreciation/Amortization']
```

Kindly advise how to using XPath to extract the date?

Comment: This page since it used ajax,You can try to another way to do that.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA, could you advise how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use requests and get data as JSON (python dictionary). If you look at the network, the website is calling API behind to fetch its data. This is how I would do it:

```
import requests
httpx = requests.Session()

# URLS
URL_Financials = 'https://www.reuters.com/companies/api/getFetchCompanyFinancials/IMAX.P'


response = httpx.get(URL_Financials)

data = response.json()

print(data)
```

The data is now a dictionary and you can get your values as you would any python dictionary.

See also these URLS:

```
URL_QUOTE = 'https://www.reuters.com/companies/api/getFetchCompanyQuote/IMAX.P'
URL_OUOTES = 'https://www.reuters.com/companies/api/getFetchQuotes/.DJI,.SPX,.IXIC,.GSPTSE,.FTSE,.GDAXI,.FCHI,.TRXFLDEXPU,.N225,.HSI,.BSESN,.NSEI,.SSEC,.XU100,.JALSH,.TRXFLDAFPU,.TRXFLDZAP'
```

Converting revenue data to Pandas

```py
# ...

from functools import reduce
import pandas as pd

X = data['market_data']['financial_statements']['income']['annual']

dfs = [pd.DataFrame(X[column]).rename(columns={'value':column}) for column in X.keys() if len(X[column])==6]

df = reduce(lambda x, y: pd.merge(x, y, on ='date'), dfs)

print(df)
```

[image]

Comment: Alright,If he want to crawl the Api,he also need to change the date `2019-12-31` to `31-Dec-19`.

Comment: @Prayson W. Daniel, Thanks. I know the date is inside but can it change to ponds which can be easier to view the data?There are many unrelated data there

Comment: Yes. It appears that it will be placed in a list. Current value is at index 0. I am not familiar with this website but what you see in the front-end is populated by back-end API. To get only the date, `data['financial_statements']['income']['annual']['Revenue'][0]['date']`

Comment: @Prayson W. Daniel, It is in dictionary. However, I unable to call the date `data['financial_statements']['income']['annual']['Revenue'][0]['date']` as it returns `KeyError: u'financial_statements'`

Comment: Sorry, it was as in another `key`. I printer data keys. `print(data.keys())`, this reveals the first layer keys. So the right location is `data['market_data'] ['financial_statements']['income']['annual']['Revenue'][0]['date']`

Comment: `pd.DataFrame.from_dict` unable to convert `data['market_data'] ['financial_statements']['income']['annual']` to pandas Dataframe. Anyway to convert it?

Comment: could you add how you find the `URL_Financials` in chrome inspect?

Comment: Added example to convert revenue to Pandas DataFrame. See my answer here on Chrome Dev https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56609913/how-to-scrape-data-bypassing-radio-button-using-request-in-python-3/56610291#56610291

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211351/discussion-between-prayson-w-daniel-and-bkcollection).

Answer (score 0):

Well,in the source code of the page.It doesn't have the date.So you couldn't get the date directly.(Maybe you could find the API and crawl it,but I didn't find it.)
[image]

So using selenium(you can also use xpath in selenium) can be an easy way:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url="https://www.reuters.com/companies/IMAX.P/financials/income-statement-annual")
date = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/div/div/section/div[2]/div[3]/table/thead/tr/th[2]/time").text
date
> 31-Dec-19
```